# Coroutines and variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

The first restriction on coroutines specified in  [cpp reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines#co_await) is that coroutines cannot use variadic arguments.
But when I try to use a coroutine that accepts varidaic arguments in its parameter list, for e.g.:

```
template<typename ...Args>
ReturnObject coro_with_variadic_argument1(Args ...args){
    std::cout << "size of variadic args: " << sizeof...(args) << "\n";
    co_await std::suspend_never{};
}
```

it works fine in GCC-11, Clang-14 and only MSVC-19 gives some sort warnings which doesn't seem to have anything to do with coroutines and varidaic arguments, and prints the output after the warning. See the code on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4b5oc5Wds). So what exactly does the cppreference page mean by the statement:

> Coroutines cannot use variadic arguments ...

Is there an example where creating C++ coroutines with variadic arguments is illegal ?

Comment: What you're showing is a template parameter pack, which is fine. It's variadic arguments that can't be used https://godbolt.org/z/eqhjahGen Follow the link on the cppreference page to see what is meant by variadic arguments https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments

Comment: @cigien thanks for pointing it out. I get the difference now.

Comment: Nominating for reopen, because I think there's more interesting details to be added to an answer here about *why* template packs are allowed but variadics are not.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72067910/coroutines-and-variadic-arguments#comment127339046_72067910) by [cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853), I confused variadic arguments with template parameter packs.

So the following will be an illegal coroutine:

```
ReturnObject coro_with_variadic_argument1(...) // <-- note variadic arg here 
{
    co_await std::suspend_never{}; 
}
```